# Можно ли передавать набор параметров в функцию используя объект Options с т.з. ООП?

Tags: c#, ооп, design

У нас есть объект, выполняющий некую полезную работу. Ему необходимо передать набор параметров, опций. Предположим, что кол-во параметров может доходить до 10.
Что более правильно и красиво - передавать параметры обычным образом или же создать некий класс опций, для хранения этих параметров и передавать его?

Наприме, так:

```
internal class Options
{
        public bool Debug { get; set; }
        public bool Verbose { get; set; }
        public bool StopOnErrors { get; set; }
        public bool SkipExisting { get; set; }
        public bool CheckOnly { get; set; }
        public bool Pause { get; set; }

        public char FieldDelimiter { get; set; }
        public char ListDelimiter { get; set; }

        public Options()
        {
            Debug = false;
            Verbose = true;
            CheckOnly = false;
            StopOnErrors = true;
            SkipExisting = false;
            Pause = false;
            FieldDelimiter = ',';
            ListDelimiter = ';';
        }
}
```

Comment: можно например использовать  myfunc(params object[] list)  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: @Konst - прекрасно - шесть булевских значений через запятую

Comment: У вас один тип воркера? Значения параметров меняются от вызова к вызову? или некоторые из них - глобальные настройки (Debug/Verbose)? Операций несолько? Набор параметров у операций разный, или частично совпадает? У объекта-воркера есть внутренее состояние, которое должно сохраняться между вызовами операций?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно! Но только если параметры логически связаны.

Методы с количеством параметров больше 3-5 становятся трудноподдерживаемыми. И инкапсуляция как всегда приходит нам на помощь: прячем несколько параметров внутри класса и передаем экземпляр этого класса как параметр метода. Мартин Фаулер в своей классической [книге по рефакторингу](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1308678/) выделяет это в отдельный случай: [Introduce Parameter Object](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html).

В вашем случае в качестве альтернативы также стоит рассмотреть передачу такого количества параметров как зависимость *класса*, а не *метода*.

Answer (score 1):

Да, по факту это просто повторение структур из никзоуровневых языков (с точки зрения используемого функционала, конечно), и называется такая штука [data transfer object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) / [business object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_object). Она часто критикуется за фактическое отсутствие поведения, но, по-моему, она выполняет именно ту роль, для которой создана - строгий перенос данных (в PHP, скажем, туда-сюда могут гоняться массива из чего угодно, подобный подходя "закрепляет" названия полей и форсирует консистентность кода) и не нужно от нее требовать чего-то еще. Единственное, что стоит сказать - насколько знаю, в C# есть структуры из коробки, и, наверное, лучше использовать их, если никакого поведения не предусматривается (иногда в DTO сразу встраивается минимальное форматирование или подтягивание других DTO).

В любом случае, структурой, объектом - это будет лучше, чем десяток параметров, потому что это напрочь убивает читаемость кода.

Answer (score 1):

Лично я голосую за класс.
Преимуществ масса:

1. Меньше путаницы при передаче параметров.
2. Если функций, принимающих эти параметры, скажем, много, то изменения нужно будет внести только в класс `Options`.
3. Всегда можно прибегнуть *почти* к старому подходу передачи параметров, просто немного изменив синтаксис:
   вместо

   ```
   someMethod(true, false, ... );
   ```

   использовать

   ```
   someMethod(new Options { Debug = true, Verbose = false, ... });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже выскажусь за отдельный класс, пусть он и не будет включать в себя поведение. Помимо вышеупомянутых доводов в пользу класса отмечу еще и что в случае с классом вы можете перенести логику валидации его членов (а следовательно, параметров, передаваемых методу) внутрь самого класса, а не выполнять кучу возможных поверок на валидность внутри метода

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения ООП такой класс не является классом. Но это не означает, что его нельзя использовать.

PS есть еще одна возможность в C# - именованные параметры. Они выглядят проще, чем Options - но их сложнее передавать по цепочке в другие методы. Сравните:

```
someMethod(new Options { Debug = true, Verbose = false });
```

и

```
someMethod(debug: true, verbose: false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю не делать отдельный класс для опций. И не передавать опции параметрами. Сделать эти опции свойствами того самого объекта, который "выполняет работу".

В крайнем случае - разделить опции воркера, и параметры операции. Опции сделать свойствами, параметры передавать параметрами (одним объектом, или отдельными, как удобнее).

Comment: В результате получится, что параметры обработки наживую вкручиваются в экземпляр, и перед его использованием приходится зачем-то менять все параметры, чтоб уж точно все было четко. А если он потом еще переиспользуется, то и тот, другой код должен быть уверен, что между двумя вызовами сохранилось состояние. Потом получаются [такие штуки](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6324).

Comment: Те же агрументы применимы к классу опций - параметры обработки зачем-то вкручиваются в сторонний класс, и перед тем, как передать его в операцию, надо зачем-то менять все параметры, чтобы точно было все четко. Если экземпляр воркера переиспользуется - у него есть состояние? Если нет - не надо переиспользовать. Если есть - то где гарантия что оно корректно переживет два вызова с разным набором опций? IMHO, Debug и Verbose вообще не должны быть параметрами операции - ни классом ни объектом, ни свойством. А предположений что там топикастер хочет сделать можно навысасывать из пальца сколько угодно